# “Attribute 'DebuggerBrowsable' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' delcarations.”

Tags: c#

Hey i am modding Android games with the programm "Dnspy" but I get an error after compiling.

> "Attribute 'DebuggerBrowsable' is not valid on this declaration type.
>   It is only valid on 'property, indexer, field' delcarations."

I dont really understand this code it would be awesome if you could fix the error or at least help me. Thank you!

```
[DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.Never)]
public event CharHandler OnDeath = delegate(Character A_0, int A_1)

{
};
```

Answer (score 2):

As the message says: that's not allowed. That attribute is defined with:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public sealed class DebuggerBrowsableAttribute : Attribute {...}
```

`[AttributeUsage]` is one of the few events that the compiler cares about and enforces *at compile-time*, so: fields and properties *only* - not methods, not types, and not events. Since it isn't allowed there: remove it:

```
public event CharHandler OnDeath;
```

note: there's no point creating and assigning a dummy delegate instance, either, hence I removed the bit on the right; if you're concerned about null-reference-exceptions - use the null conditional operator:

```
OnDeath?.Invoke(some, args);
```

noting that the arguments (`some` and `args`) won't be evaluated unless the event is subscribed.